# Regex for Delimiter in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

when I tried to edit a value on powershell, something stuck in my mind.

Actually, what I'm trying to do briefly is to ensure that a character in the form of a separator is **not repeated**, does not take place **at the beginning and the end**.

```
$oldString = "192.168.7.1,192.168.7.2,192.168.7.3,192.168.7.*"
```

```
Sample-1 : $oldString -replace "192.168.7.2", ""
----------
output   : 192.168.7.1,,192.168.7.3,192.168.7.*
Expected : 192.168.7.1,192.168.7.3,192.168.7.*   { ,, -> , }
 
Sample-2 : $oldString.Replace("192.168.7.2","").Replace("192.168.7.3","")
----------
output   : 192.168.7.1,,,192.168.7.*
Expected : 192.168.7.1,192.168.7.*      { ,,, -> , } If the comma is too many, it will be single.

Sample-3 : $oldString.Replace("192.168.7.1","").Replace("192.168.7.*","")
----------
output   : ,192.168.7.2,192.168.7.3,
Expected : 192.168.7.2,192.168.7.3      { Also, it will not startwith "," or endwith "," }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than trying to conditionally match leading or trailing commas, break the operation down into 3 steps:

- Split the string into an array of individual values
- Filter out the value you want to remove
- Join the values back together with a comma separator again

You can do this across multiple statements:

```bash
# split
$values = $oldString -split ','

# filter
$values = $values |Where-Object { $_ -ne '192.168.7.2' }

# join
$newString = $values -join ''
```

... or you can chain the 3 operations in a single expression:

```bash
$newString = $oldString -split ',' -ne '192.168.7.2' -join ','
```

`-split` always returns a string *array*, meaning that `-ne` will act as a filter/sieve, rather than as a boolean operator.

That means it'll work with any comparison operator that works in filter mode:

```bash
$newString = $oldString -split ',' -like '*.[1-3]' -join ','
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it, if I have understood properly:

```
$oldString -replace "^,|,$|(?<=,),+"
```

Also the https://regex101.com/ site is awesome for working out Regex's

Comment: Nicely done; note that you can provide a link to a specific regex101.com page with your regex, which automatically provides a detailed explanation and allows for interactive experimentation; in this case: https://regex101.com/r/3LfPOt/1 (it's important to configure the page to use the .NET regex engine and PowerShell's defaults, as in the linked page).

Comment: As an aside: Using `'...'` strings rather than `"..."` in regex contexts in PowerShell is a good habit to form, unless up-front string expansion (interpolation) is truly needed.
Using `"..."` can be especially tricky in the substitution operand of the `-replace` operator, where tokens such as `$1` refer to capture-group results, and if you used `"$1"`, PowerShell would try to expand `$1` as a _PowerShell variable_, (typically) resulting in the _empty string_.